# Convergence at infinitely many points in a compact set and convergence in the whole region

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on a region $\Omega$ with $|f_n| ≤ 1$ on $\Omega$. Let K be compact and contained in $\Omega$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges at infinitely many points in K. Then is it true or false that $\{f_n\}$ necessarily converges at every point of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true.

1. $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded, so by [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem) it is [*normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_family): Every subsequence of $(f_{n_k})$  of $(f_n)$  has a (locally uniformly) convergent subsequence $(f_{n_{k_l}})$.
2. On the other hand, every convergent subsequence has the same limit:
   Assume that $f_{n_{1, k}} \to F_1$ and $f_{n_{2, k}} \to F_2$,
   then $F_1(z) = F_2(z)$ for all points where the original sequence
   is convergent, i.e. for infinitely many points in $K$. $K$ is compact,
   so these points have an accumulation  point in $K$, and it follows from
   the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) that $F_1 = F_2$.

Now assume that $(f_n(a))$ is not convergent for some $a \in \Omega$.
Then there exist subsequences $(f_{n_{1, k}})$ and $(f_{n_{2, k}})$
such that both $(f_{n_{1, k}(a)})$ and $(f_{n_{2, k}}(a))$ are
both convergent but with a different limit.
According to (1), both sequences have subsequences which are convergent in $\Omega$.
According to (2),  those convergent subsequences have the same
limit. This is a contradiction.

The same argument can be used to show that $(f_n)$ is in fact *locally uniformly*
convergent, i.e. uniformly convergent on all compact subsets of
$\Omega$.