# prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(z)$ exists for all $|z|<1$(complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Assume that $f_{n}$ is holomorphic on $|z|<1$ and $|f_{n}|\le 10$. Assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(2^{-j})$ exists for each $j=1,2,3...$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(z)$ exists for all z with $|z|<1$

Comment: using the fact that dyadic numbers are  dense in $[0,1]$ and continuity of $f$ we have the limit exist in $[-1,1]$ only

Comment: Related: [Convergence at infinitely many points in a compact set and convergence in the whole region](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556011/convergence-at-infinitely-many-points-in-a-compact-set-and-convergence-in-the-wh).